# Mysql query, select last order

Tags: mysql, zen-cart

I'm trying to select the last order all clients purchased, the real purpose is to add a specific range, for instance last 3 months, and consider the last order from any client on those last 3 months, but with no orders sooner than those 3 months, so far I have this:

```
SELECT zen_orders.orders_id, zen_customers.customers_id,
    zen_orders.date_purchased,  zen_orders.orders_status
FROM  zen_orders 
INNER JOIN zen_customers
ON zen_orders.customers_id = zen_customers.customers_id
    AND zen_orders.orders_status = '3'
ORDER BY zen_customers.customers_id
```

I'm very new to mysql, this right now returns me all orders from all clients, when a client as more then one order it repeats a few rows with different order id but same customer id, but now how do I isolate just the last order from all clients with orders so that I can fit it in a range?

Answer (score 1):

```
select o.orders_id,o.customers_id,
    o.date_purchased,  o.orders_status from
(
    select max(o.orders_id) maxOrder,o.customer_id
    FROM  zen_orders o
    where o.orders_status = '3'
    group by o.customers_id
) t
inner join zen_orders o on o.orders_id = t.maxOrder
```

Comment: Hi, this is to advanced for me, I dont understand how to make the necessary changes on this draft so that I can run the query :\

Comment: Do you know the group by clause ?

Comment: very little but I understand what you did there, I'm researching examples of group by right now

Comment: you select the max order for each customer and then you use it as a derived table (subquery) to join it again with the zen_orders table to retrieve the rest of the data.

Comment: but can I use max to select max date of purchase (that would be the last order of each customer right)?

Comment: it depends on the data type of date of purchase attribute. if date only you can have duplicates, therefore you would retrieve more than one order for each customer. Why not use max aggregation with orders_id ?

Comment: I'm not that advanced, I had to view tutorials on subqueries to understand whats going on, but I dont think your query solves my problem, why are you joining on the max order? (I dont understand your subquery, what is it trying to do with max?)

Answer (score 0):

Display customer information and order information older than 30 days, and not older than 60 days.

```
 SELECT C.customers_id, C.customers_firstname, C.customers_lastname,  
    O.date_purchased, O.orders_id, O.order_total, OS.orders_status_name
        FROM  orders O
        LEFT join customers C on C.customers_id = O.customers_id
        LEFT join orders_status OS on OS.orders_status_id=O.orders_status
        WHERE 
           O.date_purchased BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 GROUP BY C.customers_id
```